# Deduplicate entries in large table that share same values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

We've got this big 'favorites' table, and we ran in to an issue that uncovered the fact that we dont have a unique constraint on `user`, `favorite_type`, and `favorite_id`. I've made a migration that will add an index on to these 3, but it won't work because we have existing data that has the same set of entries. There's other data in there too (`updated_at`, `created_at`, `id`) that is fine to lose, but makes it an imperfect match.

Is there a way in rails (3.2.x) to do this, or a way in (`my`)SQL?

I know I could pull all of them, then group by, and map over a delete of all extra elements, but it is a very large table (1mil+) and we can't have long-running migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the table structure to a new table, add the unique constraints, then insert all the records.  The duplicates will fail due to the constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE tableTmp LIKE table;
```

Add the constraints then insert all the records into the temporary table.

```
INSERT INTO tableTmp SELECT * FROM table
```

Verify the entries then drop and rename.

```
DROP TABLE table;
RENAME TABLE tableTmp TO table;
```

Comment: Hmhm, that would work. I'll give you the checkmark in a day, want to see if anyone has some clever rails trick I am not thinking of, but I have a feeling your way is going to be best.